# Check your login and password (Java Web, Servlets)

Tags: java, database, servlets, if-statement

I'm trying to verify that the user name and password entered in the JSP page with data from a database, all the parameters are coming, but even when matching data, the function returns false. What is my fault?

Here is my code:

```
public class LoginService {
    public boolean loginCheck(String username, String password){
        String query;
        String dbUsername, dbPassword;
        boolean login = false;

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/blog_u", "root", "root");
            Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
            query = "SELECT username, password FROM user;";
            stmt.executeQuery(query);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();

            while(rs.next()){
                dbUsername = rs.getString("username");
                dbPassword = rs.getString("password");

                if(dbUsername == username && dbPassword == password){
                    System.out.println("OK");
                    login = true;
                }
                System.out.println(username + password + " " + dbUsername + dbPassword);
            }
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return login;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. Use the method `equals()`

Comment: Passwords should never be stored in Strings.  [They should be stored in a `char[]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords).

Comment: Or (in this case because you have plain text passwords) let the database compare them for you. Add a `where` clause with username and password in your SQL query and check that it returns something. If it does, the user details are correct.

Comment: The actual problem is bigger than that. You're hauling the entire DB table into Java's memory and comparing every single row against the input. This is terribly inefficient. You're not understanding/utilizing the powers of the SQL language. You should write SQL queries in such way that it returns **exactly** the data you're looking for. Start learning how to use the `WHERE` clause. When used properly, the DB would then return 0 or 1 record. You can then just do `login = rs.next();`. Or don't you trust the DB in returning the desired data for the given `WHERE`?

Comment: I redid the test using WHERE, the code is smaller and easier now

Comment: As a side note: don't forget to close resources in the **finally** block.

Comment: Of course, just forget it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(dbUsername == username && dbPassword == password){
```

should change to

```
if(dbUsername.equals(username) && dbPassword.equals(password)){
```

Strings shouldn’t be compared using `==` in java. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).